# Scrolling is slow and laggy, why?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, font-face

I'm currently developing a website, you can find it [here] !

It's work in progress but still I can figure out why the scroll is so slow.

I'm totaly aware that I will need to minified my JS and probably use some of the head.js magic to reduce loading time.

Moreover, I'm using font-face on the website and the text takes ages to be displayed, is there a way of reducing that ?

Thanks for your time and patience.

Comment: Do you have any `onscroll` events?

Comment: No I don't use any onscroll events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you set `position: relative;` on body tag and `overflow-y: scroll;` on html tag.
I don't see any effect of `position: relative;` on body so I would say just remove it and move  `overflow-y: scroll;` from html to body tag

Comment: Hi micha, I tought about that as well but in fact I need position:relative / overflow-y:scroll; in order for my box-shadow: inset to be displayed properly. I tried to remove it tough but it didn't improve my scroll issue. Thanks.

Comment: Weird I tried it in Chrome before I post this message and everything works fine.

Comment: @Jk_ just add another div around everything in body and set your `position: relative;` and your box-shadow there

Comment: Hi Micha, I think it does the trick! Any idea why box-shadow on the body tag slow down the scroll process ? Cheers.